# Passing recevied data to Express code with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom

I am using node.js and express.I would like pass received data from socket.io inside div tag. According to received data from socket.io, I want to check with the for and if statements like below.

```
      - for(var i  in rows)    
        -if (rows[i]['senderID'] == "1" && rows[i]['receiverID'] == "2")
            div.direct-chat-msg
              div.direct-chat-name.pull-left
                div.direct-chat-info.clearfix
                  span.direct-chat-name.pull-left #{rows[i]['senderID']} 
                  span.direct-chat-timestamp.pull-right #{rows[i]['sentDate']}
                img.direct-chat-img(src="/images/users/avatar04.png", alt="alt")
                div.direct-chat-text #{rows[i]['message']} 
        -else if (rows[i]['senderID'] == "2" && rows[i]['receiverID'] == "1")
              div.direct-chat-msg.right  
                div.direct-chat-name.pull-right
                  div.direct-chat-info.clearfix
                    span.direct-chat-name.pull-left #{rows[i]['senderID']}
                    span.direct-chat-timestamp.pull-right #{rows[i]['sentDate']}
                  img.direct-chat-img(src="/images/users/avatar.png", alt="alt") 
                  div.direct-chat-text #{rows[i]['message']}    
        -else
              div.direct-chat-msg.right  
                p No message!
    div.box-footer
      div.input-group
        input.form-control(type="text" id="message" placeholder="Write a message...")
        span.input-group-btn
          button.btn.btn-danger.btn-flat(type="submit" onclick="sendMessageJS()") Send
```

How can i run this code to under the following HTML tag:

```
div.direct-chat-messages(id="chatArea")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with adding new an html variable. For examples

```
var content = '<div class = "direct-chat-msg">' +
                        '<div class = "direct-chat-name pull-left">' +
                            '<div class = "direct-chat-info clearfix">' +
                                '<span class = "direct-chat-name pull-left">' + data[i]["senderID"] + '</span>' +
                                '<span class = "direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">' + data[i]["sentDate"] + '</span>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<img class = "direct-chat-img" src= "/images/users/avatar04.png" alt = "resim">' +
                            '<div class= "direct-chat-text">'+ data[i]["message"] +'</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
var chatArea = document.getElementById("chatArea");
chatArea.innerHTML += content;
```